# Jhipster created_date column automatic?

Tags: jhipster

I want to use either jhipster JDL or command to generate an entity that's contain created_date like the default jhi_user entity. In this one we can see that the created_date is defined as timestamp and is automatically fill during a new user creation, and the field is not display in the front side. (I'm using monolithic)

Is there is any way to achieve that with the generator ?

I try with this kind of jdl line:

```
entity TestDate {
  createdDate Instant
}
```

But it's didn't create a timestamp column type in liquibase, instead it's generating this :

```xml
<column name="created_date" type="${datetimeType}">
```

And i then see in the entities view that i can select the created_date value before creating it. So it's not managed by the database itself.

Comment: There's a blueprint for this https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-entity-audit